# Convert POST HTML data from textarea to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have a text area in a form, when i insert some html code with table formatting, it converts in PDF on localhost with all formattings, but when i do same on my hosting shared and on my VPS both it does not show formatting, I have attached both images on local host and live hosting,

POST html data is stored in a variable, it contains about 120 check boxes with text, about 30 text fields with data

when i use same html pre-stored in a variable then it works, when i use from $_POST variable it gives bad results like in picture 2

please let me know how i can make it work on both sides, equally

Picture 1 (Good result on localhost)

[image]

Picture 2 (Result with HTML from $_POST variable and on hosting)

[image]

Comment: Try comparing `phpinfo()` on both servers and search for `pdf`. Likely one doesn't have the necessary software, but we can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: What king of pdf processing library are you using?
The solution regarding POST/variable make the ouput correct on the VPS?

Answer (score 0):

when you get an checkbox value via php $_POST this return on if it is checked and off is not :

```
<?
$state = "";
$myvar = $_POST['mycheck'];
if($myvar=="on") $state = "checked";

print "<input type='checkbox' name='mych' $state>";
?>
```